R: how to match sets of keywords with predefined categories?
I am working in R. I have a (large) dataset (data.frame) in which I have multiple keywords for an observation, and per observation I would like to match (convert) these keywords into a predefined category (also present as another data.frame). I got stuck with this, so I would appreciate getting some pointers on how to achieve this.
Thanks,
G
Inputs:
A)
a data.frame (input.df) with multiple observations (S1, S2, S3, ....) and associated keywords; these keywords may be in random order, and may differ in number. For example, observations S1, S2 and S4 have 3 keywords associated with them (potentially in random order), but S3 has only 2 keywords.
B)
another data.frame (season.df) that for predefined categories contain a set of keywords.
input.df <- data.frame("observation" = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S3", "S3", "S4", "S4", "S4"),
                       "keyword" = c("freezing", "snow", "slippery", "slippery", "snow", "freezing", "snow", "freezing", "sun", "hot", "airco") )

season.df <- data.frame("Winter" = c("slippery", "freezing", "snow"),
                        "Summer" = c("sun", "airco", "hot") )

> input.df
   observation  keyword
1           S1 freezing
2           S1     snow
3           S1 slippery
4           S2 slippery
5           S2     snow
6           S2 freezing
7           S3     snow
8           S3 freezing
9           S4      sun
10          S4      hot
11          S4    airco
> season.df
    Winter Summer
1 slippery    sun
2 freezing  airco
3     snow    hot
>

Expected output:
Based on the keyword(s), I would like to 'convert' each observation to a predefined category.
So in the example above I would like to categorize S1 (3 keywords) to Winter, S2 (3 words) to Winter, S3 (2 words) to Winter, and S4 to Summer.
As said, any pointers to get started would be appreciated!

Try left_join with pivot_longer:
library(tidyverse)

new.df <- left_join(
  input.df, 
  pivot_longer(season.df, everything(), names_to = "category", values_to = "keyword"),
  by = "keyword")

Output:
> new.df
   observation  keyword category
1           S1 freezing   Winter
2           S1     snow   Winter
3           S1 slippery   Winter
4           S2 slippery   Winter
5           S2     snow   Winter
6           S2 freezing   Winter
7           S3     snow   Winter
8           S3 freezing   Winter
9           S4      sun   Summer
10          S4      hot   Summer
11          S4    airco   Summer


An approach using grepl with the colnames of season.df by matching keyword
transform(input.df, observation = sapply(keyword, \(x) 
  colnames(season.df)[grepl(x, season.df)]))
   observation  keyword
1       Winter freezing
2       Winter     snow
3       Winter slippery
4       Winter slippery
5       Winter     snow
6       Winter freezing
7       Winter     snow
8       Winter freezing
9       Summer      sun
10      Summer      hot
11      Summer    airco

or, using merge
merge(with(input.df, data.frame(keyword)), 
      setNames(stack(season.df), c("values", "observation")), 
      by.x = "keyword", by.y = "values", all.x = T)
    keyword observation
1     airco      Summer
2  freezing      Winter
3  freezing      Winter
4  freezing      Winter
5       hot      Summer
6  slippery      Winter
7  slippery      Winter
8      snow      Winter
9      snow      Winter
10     snow      Winter
11      sun      Summer

